# Interior Installation Order

Tags: flooring

I'm building a new walk in closet. I've framed a few walls, ripped up the carpet, installed drywall and lighting.

Now I am going to a door jamb and casing and vinyl flooring. What goes down first, the flooring or the door jamb? Thanks!

Comment: door jamb before drywall, flooring and baseboard is last.

Comment: I disagree, there is absolutely nothing wrong with installing a door jamb after drywall. That is standard practice in nearly all residential projects.  Having to mask every jamb for texture, prime and paint would be a pain. If it were a commercial project with hollow metal frames then yes, frames first as the drywall tucks behind the frame to lock it in.

Comment: I put drywall on, originally with the intention of using corner beads to square things off, but mudding four corners in close proximity would've been a nightmare. Does door jamb also include casing?

Comment: If you put the flooring down first, you won’t have to do any precise cutting at the bottom of the door jamb. (But do any drywall trimming before flooring for ease of cleanup.) And base/ casing are after everything.

Answer (score 2):

Either works, if done correctly.

If you install the door jamb first, leave space at the bottom (shim it up, trim it to that length) to slip the flooring underneath it.

Or, install flooring first and set the jamb on top of it.

When laying new flooring on top of old, (with jambs in place) it's standard practice to cut the jambs off so the the new flooring can go under them, to the point where a special saw exists just for that job. If you trim the jamb while installing it, you don't need one.

[image: Jamb saw in use]

*[Image source](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tools4flooringandmore.co.uk%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2FR1056-Longneck-Jambsaw-In-Use.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=387216e4c97b7adfcb86679881d509d1d5bc97c3a8f3597abeba812ffcda6185&ipo=images) no affiliation or endorsement*

Comment: Jamb saws are awesome. I've used them many times. You can get by with a oscillating multitool if you have one and don't want to buy a jamb saw.

Answer (score 0):

I did the jamb first. That was a mistake because I had to cut the flooring around the jamb and this produced gaps

Comment: If it’s any comfort, much of my working knowledge comes from mistakes. Next level is to fix those mistakes elegantly. (Maybe caulk will help in your case.)